# How to ignore previous input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to create a while loop function with digits. Basically, my function is to keep adding up numbers until a non-digit is entered, and then I can break the loop. However, when I enter a non-digit input, the non-digit also get added to the equation and result in an error.

How can I exclude the non digit from the equation?

```
sum_num = 0

while True:
    num = input("Please input a number: ")
    sum_num = int(sum_num) + int(num)
    if num.isdigit() != True:
        print(sum_num)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be using a `try except` to catch the error. This makes it clear that you are avoiding such.

The reason your code doesn't work is because you are trying to add the "nondigit" (string) to a "digit" (integer) before you even check if this is possible, which you do after you've already caused the error. If you move the if statement above, your code will work:

```
sum_num = 0

while True:
    num = input("Please input a number: ")
    if num.isdigit() != True:
        print(sum_num)
        break
    sum_num = int(sum_num) + int(num)
```

Comment: change `if num.isdigit() != True:` to `if not num.isdigit():`, is more readable.

Comment: I'm only showing OP how to fix the issue using their current code, if they want to write it like they did I'm not going to change it

Comment: It is only a recommendation, the answers not only serve the OP, serve future readers who often take as reference the code, so I suggested the change to have a more readable code, if you want you do it and if not, there is no problem . :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap it in a try/except it should do what you want.

```
while True:
    num = input("Please input a number: ")
    try:
        sum_num = int(sum_num) + int(num)
    except ValueError as ex:
            print(sum_num)
            break
```